# how to stream data in unix

Tags: unix, ssh, streaming

How to stream data to a remote server in unix? I do not want to do ssh.

Currently what I am doing on local machine is: `cat local_file | ssh root@remote_machine "cat >> remote_file"`

But this file is large and I want a lighter way than ssh. I do not care about security or ack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `netcat`:

- http://netcat.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/having-fun-with-netcat-_268.html

Comment: Thanks Bruno. This can get files, would it stream data?

Comment: It will stream whatever you send to its standard input, depending on the configuration options (I'm not sure the linuxforums article is up to date). The `nc` man page should give you some examples: http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc (See perhaps `-k` option and "Data Transfer" section)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably more of a [server fault](http://servefault.com) question, but I would recommend something like [TFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol) if you have access to the remote server.  Otherwise,  [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) is not a bad mechanism for file transfers.

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially speed up the transfer by choosing a different encryption method for the ssh transfer, for example `-c blowfish` (this presumes that this is the cause of the slowdown you imply).  The ssh manpage notes: *blowfish is a fast block cipher; it appears very secure and is much faster than 3des. [...] The default is 3des*.

As noted, scp would potentially be useful here; it takes the `-c` option, too.